# transpose rows into column

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

I would like to transpose 3 rows into 3 columns like 2,3,4 row as 1,2,3 column, I tried using Macros coding but it didn't help me much.This is my data-set which requires to be transposed--

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can copy-paste the data in transposed format, which will work unless you need to do this over and over again. Copy the data you would like to transpose, and then use ctrl-alt-V and select transpose to paste it transposed in a new area.

Comment: but manual copy pasting of 100 rows of data would be not feasible :(